# Where should custom statup code live in django projects?

Tags: python, django, gunicorn, startup, wsgi

While, switching to **gunicorn** on my current project, I understood that the way I handled *model caching* on startup was not a good one.

## Setting

- app name: website
- project name: personal_cms

There are several models I equipped with a `load` method.

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    something      = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    something_else = models.URLField()

    @classmethod
    def load(cls):
        cache.set('{}'.format(cls.__name__), cls.objects.all(), None)
```

Typically, **signals** call these methods every time something change in the model. To load those **while starting the server**, I just added the following in `wsgi.py`:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'personal_cms.settings')

from website.models import SomeModel, SomeOtherModel
SomeModel.load()
SomeOtherModel.load()

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

## The problem

The code above works, but only using while using `python manage.py runserver`, not `gunicorn personal_cms.wsgi:application`. The reason, from what I understood, is that running `manage.py` comes with a specific context. Without it, apps aren't loaded when gunicorn hits `wsgi.py`:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Now that I think about it, it seems wrong to load the app's models from the project's `wsgi.py`. So, where should I call the `load` methods so that models are cached on startup no mater the wsgi server chosen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All startup code should go in the `ready` method of an AppConfig. Then reference the config class, rather than the app name, on IBSTALLED_APPS. This is guaranteed to be called at startup.

See the [AppConfig docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications)

Comment: I tried it but the problem is that, when I first initialize an instance of my application (`docker-compose up`) tables does not exist yet and I get a `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'cms_db_prod.website_somemodel' doesn't exist")`. I've been a bit wobbly on this one: even by adding `python manage.py migrate` in the `entrypoint.sh`, I get this error

Comment: But this has to do with the fact that I did not think the devop part properly. Thanks for your answer @Daniel